# VBA, ThisWorkbook object doesnt support property or method

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy from one workbook to another. I first open workbook B and try to copy to workbook A. However I am getting error `Object doesnt support this property or method` on line `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("BusinessDetails").Range("C4").Paste`

Shouldn't `ThisWorkbook` refer to the workbook and module where the code is running? What am I missing here?

Thanks.

```
  Sub Update()
    
    Dim FilePath As String
    Dim fname As Variant
    Dim myPath As String
    Dim Source As Workbook
    
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    
    
    LastRowclear = WorksheetFunction.Max(Sheets("BusinessDetails").Cells(Rows.Count, "AF").End(xlUp).Row)
    Worksheets("BusinessDetails").Range("C4:AF" & LastRowclear).Clear
    myPath = "sample path"
    fname = Dir(myPath & "Business_Level_Report*")
    
    Set Source = Workbooks.Open(myPath & fname)
    With Source
    .Activate
    LastRow = WorksheetFunction.Max(Sheets("BusinessDetails").Cells(Rows.Count, "AE").End(xlUp).Row)
    Source.Sheets(1).Range("B4:AE" & LastRow).Copy
    End With
    
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("BusinessDetails").Range("C4").Paste
    
    Workbooks(fname).Close savechanges:=False
    
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no `Range.Paste` method. The problem has nothing to do with `ThisWorkbook`.

I would use the `Destination` parameter of `Range.Copy`:

```vb
Source.Sheets(1).Range("B4:AE" & LastRow).Copy _
    Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("BusinessDetails").Range("C4")
```

though you can also use `Range.PasteSpecial` with `xlPasteAll`.